# Ghidra Debugger not working

Tags: debugging, ghidra

When I try to debug one of hackadayu exercises (or any other file) using "debug c1 in dbgeng locally via GADP" I get following errors:

```
    Launch failed for {args=/C:/Users/abc/Desktop/ghidra/hackaday-u-master/session-one/exercises/c1}
ghidra.dbg.error.DebuggerUserException: Launch failed for {args=/C:/Users/abc/Desktop/ghidra/hackaday-u-master/session-one/exercises/c1}
    at ghidra.dbg.gadp.client.GadpClient.checkError(GadpClient.java:163)
    at ghidra.dbg.gadp.client.GadpClient.lambda$sendChecked$2(GadpClient.java:358)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at ghidra.async.AsyncPairingCache.fulfill(AsyncPairingCache.java:166)
    at ghidra.dbg.gadp.client.GadpClient.lambda$receiveLoop$4(GadpClient.java:378)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I tried running it with admin right etc. without success.

Answer (score 2):

I've just downloaded the "c1" exercise from https://github.com/wrongbaud/hackaday-u.

This is a linux elf:

```
> file c1
c1: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=d9462be5061532875d1ea68aab66366a42f87d6c, not stripped
```

You need a Linux OS (a VM will works too) in order to debug it.

You are clearly trying to run it on Windows (**C:/Users/abc/Desktop/ghidra/hackaday...**)

Comment: thank you, it worked. do you have an idea on how to debug ARM code with ghidra? I read that I need some machine that runs ARM and can run ghidra + debugger, which one could I use?

Comment: Hi, yes you need an arm based cpu (real or emulated). You can use Qemu to achieve that. Regarding the debugger, you haven't even told me what is the guest OS you want to run on that machine, but if gdb is available, then yes. Anyway this is a total different topic that can't be discussed in a "comment". Also, please accept my answer if I helped you.